# Construction of Dol Guldur

Tags: tolkiens-legendarium, sauron

The land and forests encompassing Amon Lac appear to have been constantly part of the realm of the Silvan Elves from the start of the First Age until the second millienium of the Third Age. Aside from some bands of woodsmen, the race of Men seem to have avoided, or at least ignored the area, as it lay outside the reach of Numenor (later, of Gondor or Arnor). The same seems true of the Dwarves, who besides building a trade road through, preferred to stay in their mountain halls.

Then suddenly into the tale appears the Fortress of Dol Guldur Was it a mini-Barad-Dur, or a hole in the ground there lived a corrupted Maiar? It IS described as a 'fortress', it had dungeons, and was large enough to serve as a garrison for a force of orcs strong enough to threaten both Lorien and the Woodland Realm simultaneously. Did Sauron and his servants construct a new entity, or simply occupy an existing one dating from earlier history?

Comment: Thank you. This link does more or less answer it, unless someone has more to add. search did not bring this up. this is my second try here on SE - is the protocol that I now delete my question?

Comment: You don't need to delete this question. If the link above answered your question to your satisfaction, I think there is a link somewhere above where you can confirm that it's a duplicate. If part of your question is still unanswered, you can edit the question to indicate the difference between this and the linked question.